# Tracker Network Python API key error

Tags: python, api

I am trying to fetch data from this website: https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api and I'm having some issues with authenticating my get request; keep getting **error 403**.

My code:

```
import requests

headers = {'TRN-Api-Key':'*My API Key*','User-Agent': '*My user Agent*'}

r = requests.get("https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/*My Username*",headers=headers)

print(r)
```

I have checked that the key is correct and have passed a valid User-Agent.

So yeah, I'm probably doing something very silly or perhaps there is a bug with authentication on the website, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Do they have the API actually documented anywhere? I don't see where it tells you what header to use.

Comment: @glibdud *TRN-Api-Key* is the header with which you need to pass the key with your request, they don't have any documentation as far as I am aware apart from the bare bones on the API section of their website.